# Symfony2 OneToMany Form Existing "One-Record"

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I implemented a form for my example: Author And Book. (OneToMany relation)
(Author has firstname and lastname in form to be entered and Book has got a title that needs to be entered in the same form)

It works fine, but what if an Author record with firstname and lastname already exists?

I thought of something like:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AuthorRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findByFirstnameAndLastname($firstname, $lastname)
{
    $parameters = array(
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname
    );

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a FROM AcmeUserBundle:Author a WHERE a.firstname = :firstname AND 
            a.lastname = :lastname')
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->getResult();
}
}
```

Creating my Repository Class and checking there if the Record already exists.
So i'm new to Symfony and have no idea if this is the recommended way and how to persist then
the Data into the database with the already existing Author-record.

My Controller:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Author;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Book;
use Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\AuthorType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function createAuthorAndBookAction(Request $request){

    $author = new Author();
    $author->addBook(new Book());

    $form = $this->createForm(new AuthorType(), $author);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){

        // check if author already exists ?
        $firstname = $form["firstname"]->getData();
        $lastname = $form["lastname"]->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $author = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Author')
            ->findByFirstnameAndLastname($firstname, $lastname);

        // End echk 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($author);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Main:author.html.twig', array('form' => 
    $form->createView()));
}
}
```

I just started by checking if an Author exists with the firstname and lastname entered in the form, but i don't know as mentioned above if this is correct and how to go further on.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DataTransformers` in your form to "transform" the 2 fields `lastname` and `firstname` into an author object that will be map to your foreign key.

These two field have to be into a subform to attach the dataTransformer to it.

When your transformer does not find an author it could return a `new Author` entity object.
(You have to make your form as a service to pass the repository to the transformer Repository.

Hope these explanations help.